# Convertir un string a numero con signo

Tags: vb.net, string, vb, double

Necesito convertir un string con el siguiente formato -0.0092 a un tipo de numero con el que pueda operar mas tarde, he probado con Val, o CdBl y ambos pierden el signo o truncan el resultado final...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `Double.Parse` por ejemplo:

```
Double.Parse("-0.0092")
```

Pero es posible que te encuentres con un resultado inesperado, ya que en nuestra cultura normalmente se considera que el separador decimal es `,`, no `.`.

En ese caso, lo mas seguro es lo siguiente, usar `InvariantCulture` en la cual el separador decimal es el `.`:

```
Dim numdbl As Double = Double.Parse("-0.0092", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: No funciona, para la ejecucion cuando hace el parse incluso sustituyendo "." por ","

Comment: @marcss Si funciona, lo acabo de comprobar [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rRhxTM). Si en tu caso no es así, edita tu pregunta añadiendo el código que estás usando y asegurate de que tu cadena de entrada sea la que crees. Si dices que "para la ejecución" es que la cadena que le estas pasando no se considera un numero valido.Edita tu pregunta poniendo el código de error y que string le estas pasando exactamente

Comment: Me aparece el siguiente error: El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
Excepción producida: 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll

Comment: @marcss como te digo, el problema es casi seguro que en la cadena que intentas convertir hay algun caracter inesperado. Depura el codigo y mira a ver si hay algun caracter extraño en la cadena que tratas de convertir

Comment: Tenias razón he debugeado y habia un caracter no imprimible que impedio convertirlo. Muchas gracias!